# Post form data onclick event of button using ajax in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I hava a PHP MVC project. I read data from database and create a form for each record. I want to make update when pressed the button which it is in the form. But I confused how I can access form elements in javascript function. I used an index for each record but I could not overcome how I can find it in javascript.

My php file:

```
$index = 1;
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <form id="updateForm">
            <div style="visibility: hidden">
                <input type="text" name="editId<?php echo "$index"?>" id="editId<?php echo "$index"?>" value="<?php echo $category['id']; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="editTitle<?php echo "$index"?>" id="editTitle<?php echo "$index"?>"
                       value="<?php echo $category['title']; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <select class="form-control" name="editline<?php echo "$index"?>" id="editline<?php echo "$index"?>">
                    <option disabled selected value="">Sıra</option>
                    <?php
                    for ($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++) {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                <a class="btn btn-success" id="btnUpdateSubmit" name="btnUpdateSubmit" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/category"
                   onclick="updatecategory();"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Kaydet</a>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#"><i class="icon-trash icon-large"></i> Sil</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
$index++;
```

And my javascript function:

```
function updatecategory() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhtpp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhtpp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("existCategories").innerHTML = xmlhtpp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhtpp.open("POST", '<?php echo BASE_URL ?>/category');
}
```

Comment: just pass the index as a parameter in the function call as well something like onclick="updatecategory($i); and give each option a distinct id with index like <option id="Identity_<?php echo $i; ?>">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. remove the ID from the form - IDs must be unique.
2. Change the links to submit buttons
3. add an event hander:

---

```
window.onload=function() {
  var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
  for (var i=0;i<forms.length;i++) {
    forms[i].onsubmit=function() {
       updateCategory(this);
       return false; // cancel submit
    }
  }
}
```

then have

```
function updatecategory(theForm) {
  var categoy = theForm.elements[0].value; // editIdxxx
```

Comment: I tried that but event handler didn't work. I mean I used alert in the event handler but nothing happened.

Comment: Does the server accept the call? Any errors in console?

Comment: Why window.onload does not work? I can not understand.

Comment: Neither do I. If you do not get an alert you may have another onload. Try addEventHandler instead